# Hi, I am having trouble with running my Laravel Cron job on shared hosting "hostinger"

Tags: laravel, shared-hosting

my Cron job works fine on localhost but it doesn't work on shared hosting and it doesn't return any error or something.
this how I'm calling my Cron job:
php /path_to_my_project/public_html/myproject artisan queue:work
my queue driver is database and here's my code:

```
ChangePassword::dispatch($user)->delay(now()->endOfMinute()->addMinutes(1));
```

Comment: Hi, On shared hosts, the cron process settings are usually turned off. If there is a cron section in the host management panel given to you, you can make adjustments. Otherwise, I recommend contacting your host administrator. This feature will be turned off on shared servers.

Comment: find the path to php and specify it in your job.  
ps. You are risking security issues putting your entire project in public_html

Comment: @nrkdrk , I did contact them, and they are saying that everything is fine

Comment: @Snapey , what do you mean to find the path of php?

Comment: @kinanAl-Midani well, did you add the cron client to the commands array in app/console/kernel?
and can you check this link https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling

Comment: Use the console and type `which php`.  Also, make sure you have the slash between the path to your project and the artisan command as I wrote in my answer below.  In your question, you have a space

Comment: When you say "here's my code"  that code is for dispatching a queued job.  What has it got to do with CRON ?

Comment: @Snapey , I don't have console on shared hosting as you know, and where should I write this which php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cron command needs to be more like;

```
/usr/local/bin/php /path_to_my_project/public_html/myproject/artisan queue:work
```

if you have console access type `which php` to check the path of php

WARNING: check that your .env file is not vulnerable since you put your project inside public_html

Comment: I tried that and didn't work

Comment: yes i also tried this, but still not working